# "Are we good?" vs. "Are we good to go"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

What is the difference in meaning between:

> Are we good?

or:

> We're good?

and:

> Are we good **to go**?

I would appreciate it if you could as well give some examples for usage of each phrase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phrase 1

> Are we good?/We're good?

I don't hear "We're good?" often, and admittedly, it sounds a little strange to me. But I believe that it can work or that it is understandable. Oddly enough, the slang/incorrect "We good?" sounds more natural/popular than "We're good?" (but that's my opinion). As for "Are we good?",
this can have a few different meanings.
*Example 1.*
A man and a woman have had a small disagreement. The man becomes nervous that their relationship might end and asks "Are we good?"
He could be asking "Is our relationship ok?", or it could mean "Are you still mad at me?"

*Example 2.*
Some friends are being chased by a monster through the woods. They finally escape the woods, and some asks "Are we good?" He is asking, "Is it safe?" or "Are we safe?"

*Example 3.*
A family has packed their stuff in the car and everyone is eager to leave and begin their trip. The dad, at the wheel, asks "Are we good?"

In other words, he is asking "Is everyone ready?", "Is everyone ready to go?".

---

Phrase 2

> Are we good to go?

My impression is that this has the same meaning as example 3 above.

It could also mean "Are we ready to begin?", as in begin to watch a movie, a class, or other things that can start.

---

So Phrase 2 is usually used to ask if we can begin something, like trip or a movie. It can refer to physical movement, but it doesn't have to (like watching a movie). But it would not be used in the sense of examples 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! Just one question. Does "we good?" mean the same thing as "Are we good"? If no, can you please add the meaning of that phrase to your answer too?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. Just remember, it is slang/grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much. (I'm not sure thanking people in the comments is considered fine on this website. Please someone let me know if it is so that I remove my unnecessary comment s.)

Comment: Technically, no. But I doubt it is enforces heavily. It is recommend that you up vote or accept an answer by giving it a check mark. You can read more [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: "we good" is not incorrect, it's just what's known as conversational elision, where (usually) words that open sentences are dropped - auxiliaries etc - (are) you all right?  [ https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/1rbeks/scholarly_work_on_conversational_deletion/ ]

Answer (score 2):

"We're good?" is not usually expressed as a question.  That would more likely be in the form "We good?" being short for "[Are] we good?" for reasons already expressed in the other replies.

"We're good", as a statement or an answer to a question, would be more common.

Example:

Q: "What is the situation?"

A: "We're good."

Thus, the answer in this case implies that whatever the concern is, it has been dealt with.